# When does a mount get healing?

Tags: dnd-4e, healing, mounted-combat

In one game I'm currently playing, I have a Riding Horse which has just taken damage as part of an aura.  This helped me to better realize that the horse is indeed a creature - not just a piece of equipment.

So, my next pondering thought became "How do I heal this horse, if he gets too beat up?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Your mount has one surge per tier.  It does not have a second wind.**

This is defined in the glossary<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=160)</sup>

> Monsters and NPCs: As a general rule, monsters and nonplayer characters have a number of healing surges based on their tier: one healing surge at the heroic tier (1st–10th levels), two healing surges at the paragon tier (11th–20th levels), and three healing surges at the epic tier (21st–30th levels).

Without a second wind, you will need to provide your mount with any healing necessary or wait until the end of a short rest to allow the mount to use its healing surge(s) by itself.